# Threads failing to affect performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Below is a small program meant to parallelize the approximation of the 1/(n^2) series. Note the global parameter `NUM_THREADS`.

My issue is that increasing the number of threads from 1 to 4 (the number of processors my computer has is 4) does not significantly affect the outcomes of timing experiments. Do you see a logical flaw in the `ThreadFunction`? Is there false sharing or misplaced blocking that ends up serializing the execution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex sum_mutex;           // This mutex is for the sum vector
std::vector<double> sum_vec;    // This is the sum vector
int NUM_THREADS = 1;
int UPPER_BD = 1000000;

/* Thread function */
void ThreadFunction(std::vector<double> &l, int beg, int end, int thread_num)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = beg; i < end; i++) sum += (1 / ( l[i] * l[i]) );
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1 (sum_mutex, std::defer_lock);
    lock1.lock();
    sum_vec.push_back(sum);
    lock1.unlock();
}

void ListFill(std::vector<double> &l, int z)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < z; ++i) l.push_back(i);
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> l;
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_vec;

    ListFill(l, UPPER_BD);
    int len = l.size();

    int lower_bd = 1;
    int increment = (UPPER_BD - lower_bd) / NUM_THREADS;
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; ++j)
    {
        thread_vec.push_back(std::thread(ThreadFunction, std::ref(l), lower_bd, lower_bd + increment, j));
        lower_bd += increment;
    }

    for (auto &t : thread_vec) t.join();
    double big_sum;
    for (double z : sum_vec) big_sum += z;

    std::cout << big_sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR; What actually makes you think that having multiple threads could improve your performance? It could even hurt performance, if not used correctly, and with how many _really parallel available CPU's_ the application is running.

Comment: I believe your program exhibits undefined behavior. You pass a local variable to `ThreadFunction` by reference, but do nothing to ensure that variable lives long enough. It's not even clear why you need `l` vector - just pass a pair of integers, low and high bound, directly to the thread. You are spending a lot of time - sequentially on the main thread - just filling `l`; possibly more time than you spend actually doing the math.

Comment: Why are you using `defer_lock` and calling `lock()` and `unlock()` manually?

Comment: Igor -- that makes sense, thanks. For the purpose of this example though, I'm more interested in learning how to properly distribute work to threads, given a vector of inputs. The idea is that the ListFill function would be replaced by an external file to process, whose contents would be distributed among threads. I will look into whether the time difference is small due to the majority of time being spent on the ListFill function.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well, it cannot anymore. The question has been edited after I posted my comment; an act without honor.

Comment: Ah, I see! @ZakirGowani, you also need to initialize `big_sum` or your sum starts with a garbage value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your code, I suspect that ListFill is taking longer than ThreadFunction.  Why pass a list of values to the thread instead of the bounds each thread should loop over?   Something like:

```
void ThreadFunction( int beg, int end ) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(double i = beg; i < end; i++) 
         sum += (1.0 / ( i * i) );
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1 (sum_mutex);
    sum_vec.push_back(sum);
}
```

To maximize parallelism, you need to push as much work as possible onto the threads.  See [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dohashi's nice improvement, you can remove the need for the mutex by populating the `sum_vec` in advance in the main thread:

```
sum_vec.resize(4);
```

then writing directly to it in `ThreadFunction`:

```
sum_vec[thread_num] = sum;
```

since each thread writes to a distinct element and doesn't modify the vector itself there is no need to lock anything.